# Documenting JSON in URL not possible

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-restdocs

In my Rest API it should be possible to retrieve data which is inside a bounding box. Because the bounding box has four coordinates I want to design the GET requests in such way, that they accept the bounding box as JSON. Therefore I need to be able to send and document JSON strings as URL parameter.

The test itself works, but I can not document these requests with Spring RestDocs (1.0.0.RC1). I reproduced the problem with a simpler method. See below:

```
  @Test public void ping_username() throws Exception
  {
    String query = "name={\"user\":\"Müller\"}";
    String encodedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
    mockMvc.perform(get(URI.create("/ping?" + encodedQuery)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(document("ping_username"));
  }
```

When I remove `.andDo(document("ping_username"))` the test passes.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 32: http://localhost:8080/ping?name={"user":"Müller"}
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcOperationRequestFactory.createOperationRequest(MockMvcOperationRequestFactory.java:79)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationResultHandler.handle(RestDocumentationResultHandler.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andDo(MockMvc.java:158)
    at application.rest.RestApiTest.ping_username(RestApiTest.java:65)
```

After I received the suggestion to encode the URL I tried it, but the problem remains.

The String which is used to create the URI in my test is now `/ping?name%3D%7B%22user%22%3A%22M%C3%BCller%22%7D`.

I checked the class `MockMvcOperationRequestFactory` which appears in the stacktrace, and in line 79 the following code is executed:

```
URI.create(getRequestUri(mockRequest)
                + (StringUtils.hasText(queryString) ? "?" + queryString : ""))
```

The problem here is that a not encoded String is used (in my case `http://localhost:8080/ping?name={"user":"Müller"}`) and the creation of the URI fails.

**Remark:**

Andy Wilkinson's answer is the solution for the problem. Although I think that David Sinfield is right and JSONs should be avoided in the URL to keep it simple. For my bounding box I will use a comma separated string, as it is used in [WMS 1.1](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.1/user/services/wms/basics.html): `BBOX=x1,y1,x2,y2`

Comment: Your url does not conform to RFC1738. Curly braces are 'unsafe" and need to be url encoded and decoded.

Comment: The encoding is the problem, but apparently there is a bug in Spring Restdocs. See my edit.

Comment: I can't see why the ternary expression would fail. Unless the ? is being url encoded and not found. Is it necessary to make problems for yourself? Can't you use Rest as originally intended with a plain text query string. Why complicate things with a JSON string that is not URL compatible?

Comment: In the meantime I also think that using JSON strings in the URL is not the best idea. I am quite new to REST and web development and I thought it would be nice to have (JSON) objects around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  haven't mentioned the version of Spring REST Docs that you're using, but I would guess that the problem is with `URIUtil`. I can't tell for certain as I can't see where `URIUtil` is from.

Anyway, using the JDK's `URLEncoder` works for me with Spring REST Docs 1.0.0.RC1:

```
String query = "name={\"user\":\"Müller\"}";
String encodedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
mockMvc.perform(get(URI.create("/baz?" + encodedQuery)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andDo(document("ping_username"));
```

You can then use `URLDecoder.decode` on the server side to get the original JSON:

```
URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8")
```

Comment: If I use your solution but remove the `URI.create()` then it works. Is your `URI.create()` intended?

Comment: It was, but only to be as close to your original code as possible. AFAIK, it should work both with and without it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that URIs have to be encoded as ACII. And `ü` is not a valid ASCII character, so it must be escaped in the url with `%` escaping.

If you are using Tomcat, you can use `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in the `Connector` element of the `server.xml`, to configure UTF-8 escaping as default. If you do this, `ü` will be automatically converted to `%C3%BC`, which is the ASCII representation of the `\uC3BC` Unicode code-point (which represents `ü`).

---

**Edit:** It seems that I have missed the exact point of the error, but it is still the same error. Curly braces are invalid in a URI. Only the following characters are acceptable according to RFC 3986:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=%
```

So these must be escaped too.

Comment: This may well be true but the error is reported at index 32...the first curly brace.

Your error might well surface when the curly brace problem is fixed.

Comment: I missed the correct index, but curly braces are invalid too.